# Issues with smtplib sending mails

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

I tried following a youtube video on how to use smtplib to send emails, however whenever I try to send anything it gives me this error.

```
in alert_mail
    msg.set_content(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/email/message.py", line 1162, in set_content
    super().set_content(*args, **kw)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I really don't know why as I followed the video very closely, only changing the Gmail credentials and passwords to my own test accounts.

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

def alert_mail(subject, body, to):
    msg = EmailMessage
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg["subject"] = subject
    msg["to"] = to

    user = "helios.alert.system@gmail.com"
    msg["from"] = user
    password = #2 way encription password would be here, but thats not the issue 

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user,password)
    server.send_message(msg)

    server.quit()

alert_mail("Hey","Hey this is my first com method" , "helios.alert.system@gmail.com") # sends email to itself, doesn't work even when some different address is entred
```

Any advice will be appreciated!

The video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1IsCbXp0uE

Comment: you're missing `()` when initialising `EmailMessage()`

Answer (score 0):

You should add an opening and closing parenthesis to the `msg = EmailMessage` line, remember that `EmailMessage` is an object, so you must use the correct syntax for creating one. This code below should work:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(GMAIL_SERVER, GMAIL_PORT)
server.starttls()

server.login(EMAIL_SOURCE, PWD_SOURCE)
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['From'] = EMAIL_SOURCE
msg['To'] = TO_EMAIL
msg['Subject'] = YOUR_SUBJECT
msg.set_content(bodyOfMail)

server.send_message(msg)

del msg
server.quit()
```